# How to mock SoapException using Moq to unit test error handling

Tags: c#, unit-testing, soap, error-handling, moq

I've inherited a small console application that makes calls to a SOAP web service. It's a tragic mess of nested try-catches that log exceptions in various ways, and I'd like to wrap some test coverage around how it behaves when a SoapException gets thrown.

Question: How can I mock a class like SoapException using Moq when I can't mock an interface and I can't make properties or methods "virtual"?

A little more explanation:

To test this error handling, I need to control the `Actor` property of the SoapException object, as well as the `Detail` property in order to verify the error handling.

A snippet of my unit test code:

```
[TestMethod]
public void MyTestMethod()
{
    Mock<SoapException> soapMock = new Mock<SoapException>(MockBehavior.Strict);

    soapMock.SetupGet<string>(ex => ex.Actor).Returns("Test Actor");
```

Since I'm mocking a concrete class, and the `Actor` property is not marked "Virtual", Moq is throwing this exception when executing the `SetupGet(...)` line during the test run:

> System.NotSupportedException: Invalid setup on a non-virtual (overridable in VB) member: ex => ex.Actor

After some reading, the ideal answer is to mock an interface, which I am unable to do in this case. Since this is a class baked in to the .NET framework, I also can't magically mark the `Actor` property as virtual.

How can I mock a SoapException, or is there a different way I can verify the error handling?

As an aside, I first dove into creating an actual SoapException with some XML nodes inside it, but I quickly fell down the rabbit hole of programmatically creating an XML document tree. I *can* do it, but it would require many more lines of test setup code, which I'd like to avoid if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its not possible to mock it using Moq. One option is to use **Shim** from **Microsoft Fakes Framework**. You can use it in scenarios where the code you are trying to mock doesn't use interface or is a virtual method(like in your scenario).

See below explanation of Shim from msdn.

> A shim modifies the compiled code of your application at run time so
>   that instead of making a specified method call, it runs the shim code
>   that your test provides. Shims can be used to replace calls to
>   assemblies that you cannot modify, such .NET assemblies.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh549175.aspx

Note that Fakes framework is only available with Visual Studio Ultimate or Premium.

Comment: I'm going to try this out. Thanks.

Comment: I just discovered that Microsoft Fakes requires Visual Studio 2012 or newer. I have Visual Studio 2010, however I also found out that the [Microsoft Moles Framework](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/b3b41648-1c21-471f-a2b0-f76d8fb932ee/) was the predecessor for Fakes. I'm going to try that, but I'm marking this question as the answer since it is the more current answer. I'll also post my own answer for Visual Studio 2010 as well.

Answer (score 1):

I was in a same situation to mock SoapException. I used the constructor of SoapException to pass Detail, Actor etc. Below is using Rhino Mocks.

```
//Build your xmlDocument 
    SoapException mockSoapException = MockRepository.GenerateMock<SoapException>("Mock SoapException", new XmlQualifiedName(), "TEST", xmlDocument);
```

Comment: This would work, however I didn't want to hand build an XML document.